# How to get plugin as jar in android studio

Tags: android, plugins, android-studio-2.0

I need to send an associate a plugin that he can use in android studio. The plugin [is here](https://github.com/frogermcs/dagger2metrics)

I need to send it to him on a USB stick for him to install as his network will not allow the plugin to be downloaded through gradle directly. What do i need to supply ?  I look in the generated folders and i found this:

[image]

The dependency declaration for this plugin say the following:

```
dependencies {
classpath 'com.frogermcs.dagger2metrics:dagger2metrics-plugin:0.2'
```

}

Comment: `classpath  files('path_to_the_jar.jar')` ... jar can be downloaded from the [jcenter repo](https://bintray.com/)

Comment: this works, you can make an offical answer, thank you. i did classpath files('/Users/myuserID/Downloads/dagger2metrics-plugin-0.2.jar') after downloading from https://bintray.com/frogermcs/maven/dagger2metrics-plugin/view#files/com/frogermcs/dagger2metrics/dagger2metrics-plugin/0.2 and it was succcesful.